# How to use table names that have spaces in a SAS macro?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
PROC EXPORT DBMS=CSV       DATA=WORK.'TABLE NAME WITH SPACES IN IT'n
  OUTFILE="/test/TABLE NAME WITH SPACES IN IT.CSV";
RUN;
```

The above works. Below is the part of the macro that is not working. The macro does create the correct string but SAS still gives me an error.

```
%let tablename = %nrbquote(&Libname..'&Table.'n);
%put &tablename.;
    PROC EXPORT DBMS=CSV DATA=&tablename.
    OUTFILE="&outlocation.";
  RUN;
%END;
%MEND;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macro variables don't work very well within single quotation marks so if you change that to double you should be fine.

```
%let tablename = &Libname.."&Table."n;
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick! I up voted your answer but I don't have enough reputation points for it to show. Cheers.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance! I think there should be some way of making the question as answered but I'm fairly new to this myself so I'm not sure.

Comment: Didn't see it before but I have now selected your answer with the green tick.

Comment: Thanks, Makes it easier to filter through all the new questions!